# Display all child nodes of selected node of treeview in textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, treeview

Not too sure on how to get around this.

I am able to display the current selected node in a textbox (or richtextbox) by doing the following:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect

    RichTextBox1.Text = e.Node.Text

End Sub
```

However, I can't figure out a way of displaying **all** child nodes of the selected parent.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You need what is called a recursive subroutine to drill down into the child nodes of each node to iterate through them:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect

    Dim myNode As TreeNode = e.Node

    TextBox1.Text = myNode.Text

    GetChildNodes(myNode)

End Sub

Sub GetChildNodes(tnode As TreeNode)

    'Iterate through the child nodes of the node passed into this subroutine
    For Each node As TreeNode In tnode.Nodes

        TextBox1.Text += node.Text

        'If the node passed into this subroutine contains child nodes,
        'call the subroutine for each one of them
        'If you only want to display one level deep, then comment out the
        'IF statement.
        If tnode.Nodes.Count > 0 Then GetChildNodes(node)

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if it resolved your issue so that anyone else with the same question will have a better idea if this is a working solution.